# Who were we in Euro 2012... Spain or Netherlands*?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm interested to know by how much Sports.SE was affected by Euro 2012?

If I remember correctly, the visitors/day was ~300 before Euro 2012, so we seem to have been successful in that regard (increasing to 461 at the time of writing...)

However, can anyone remember/ provide the number of user registrations/ *active* users before/after Euro 2012 for comparison? The site stats show 582 registered users... but I can't remember what it was before.

<sup>* Spain won, Netherlands didn't get a point ;)</sup>

Comment: +1: Interesting question, would be good to get some quantitative information on this regard....